# System.Web.WebPages assembly reference error in MVC 3 after installing MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a class library that uses System.Web.Mvc version 3 and System.Web.WebPages version 1. After installing Visual Studio 2012 (MVC version 4) I have a problem compiling this class library in Visual Studio 2010:

```
Assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' c:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll
```

In this project I do not want to use MVC 4 yet.

Comment: for less pain , use nuget to install mvc 4 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I opened the .csproj file in a text editor and found the following line:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

I noticed the `HintPath` didn't exists on my machine (Windows 7 32-bit), so apparently Visual Studio automatically takes the latest version (probably in the GAC). I removed System.Web.Mvc from the project references and added it again by browsing to the right path. The .csproj now looks like this:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 3\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Also make sure the Version argument is set to 3.0.0.0.

Comment: I was having a very similar issue to this. My hint paths were looking at Program Files instead of Program Files (x86), and even after updating that, the project was still trying to use the 4.0 version, even though the reference was specifically telling it to use 3.0. I then set the SpecificVersion property to True, and this forced the project to use 3.0.